# Updating a table row using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I need to update a certain row in table, already did "validators" to assure 1 row edit when checkbox is checked after clicking some other button,
so far I wrote something like:

```
$("#btnsavechanges").click(function(){


        $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children.eq(0).append(document.getElementById("modsub").value);
        $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children.eq(2).append(document.getElementById("modwhere").value);
        $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children.eq(3).append(document.getElementById("modwhen").value);
        $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children.eq(4).append(document.getElementById("modtime").value);
        $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children.eq(5).append(document.getElementById("modwho").value);
        $("#tblmod").fadeOut("slow");


    });
```

notice Meetingspanel is my table, and all those Modsubject and etc are my textboxes.
and tblmod is the table of all textboxes and the update button.
thanks

```
    <table id='tblmod' width='80%' align='center' >
<tr bgcolor='white'>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Subject<input type="text" id="modsubject" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Location<input type="text" id="modwhere" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter When<input type="text" id="modwhen" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Time<input type="text" id="modtime" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter With Who<input type="text" id="modwho" width="15%">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th align="right" style=border-width:0px><button type="button" id="btnsavechanges" value="Save New Changes" >Save Changes</button></th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what's the problem/question? What have you tried?

Comment: problem is, that it doesnt work...i haven't wrote it right i guess...nothing happens..entered alert after first row and it doesnt get there !

Comment: what does your table look like?

Comment: what does your table look like. I'm almost certain those selectors can be shortened down quite a bit. Also, what does the debugger show?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your markup or what you are trying to do completely, I can only point out the mistakes in your code.

1. You are using `children` as a property which is a function so use it like function `children()`.
2. Instead of using `parent().parent()` you can using `closest('tr')`.
3. If you want to update the value of input element use `val()` method, `append` will not work.
4. If the element has an id then use id selector instead of using `document.getElementById()`. This will only reduce your code no much difference though.